# Ajax post function to external URL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple post function (see bellow)

```
 $("#abi_test").click(function (event) {
    $.post(
        "get.php",
        {
            name: "Tom",
            age: "30",
            email: "johnsmith@gmail.com",
            uniID: "3"
        },
        function (data) {
            $('#stage').html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

how can i change this to post to `https://www.site.co.uk/some/get.php` ?

I have tried

```
 $("#abi_test").click(function (event) {
        $.post(
            "https://www.site.co.uk/some/get.php",
            {
                name: "Tom",
                age: "30",
                email: "johnsmith@gmail.com",
                uniID: "3"
            },
            function (data) {
                $('#stage').html(data);
            }
        );
    });
```

But did not work

**I am getting a error**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.site.co.uk/some/get.php. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://website.org.uk' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that.  It's called cross-site scripting and it is not allowed by almost all servers.  The only way around that is if you control the server you can respond with headers that allow requests from foreign URLs.

If you do control the server, then simply add this to the get.php file.  You would be best off explicitly specifying the URL it's coming from though.  Otherwise your server is vulnerable to a POST from any domain.

```
php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: thanks, how would I do this ?

Comment: Do you control the server?

Comment: yep, solved with <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>  if you edit your answer to include this ill accept your answer

Comment: Thanks, i've edited the answer.